# how to upload a CSV(partitioned by a column name) from cloud storage to BigQuery via CLI?

Tags: google-bigquery, upload, google-cloud-storage, command-line-interface, partitioning

I want to upload a CSV file(partitioned by a column name) to bigquery via CLI.For example: the table should be partitioned by a column name called "Time-Key".
Here is my current code:

```
bq load \
--source_format=CSV \
{prjectname:Datasetname.tablename} \
{cloud storage path for csv file} \
./{SchemaNames.json}
```

How do I add a partitioned parameter to this? (Ex: PARTITION BY TIME_KEY)

Comment: How you created the table? there you have the column used for partioning.

Comment: CSV table is located in Cloud Storage. I want to partition it by its column name called "Time-Key" and upload partitioned table into bigquery via CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> --time_partitioning_field
>
> The field used to determine how to create a time-based partition. If time-based partitioning is enabled without this value, the table is partitioned based on the load time.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_load